# Why my listview is empty when I switch activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I've create 2 different activity to show JSON Array with different result and show it into listview.
 
First, I create my menu activity to control switch activity with buttons (Button1 and Button2).
Then, I create 2 activitiy classes (Activity1 and Activity2) to show my JSON array in listview.
When I click Button1, it works and shows my JSON Array on my Activity1 in listview.
But when I click Button2, it shows nothing. 
Why my listview items for Activity2 lost?

here is my listview place holder (`listviewplaceholder`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my layout to get values (`wfid`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="7dp"
    >
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="13dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my menu activity (`MenuActivity`):

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button btnIndonesia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btnMalaysia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button btnSingapore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button btnHongkong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        //Listening to button event
        btnIndonesia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent indonesiaScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WeeklyFlashActivity.class);

                startActivity(indonesiaScreen);

            }
        });

        btnMalaysia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent malaysiaScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WeeklyFlashMyActivity.class);

                startActivity(malaysiaScreen);

            }
        });

        btnSingapore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent singaporeScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WeeklyFlashSgActivity.class);

                startActivity(singaporeScreen);

            }
        });

        btnHongkong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent hongkongScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WeeklyFlashHkActivity.class);

                startActivity(hongkongScreen);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

and this is my activity to show JSON array on listview `WeeklyFlashActivity` (all activity basicly similar each other the different only the URL to get the JSON):

```
public class WeeklyFlashActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.greenfields.co.id:502/Service1.svc/json/weeklyflash/id");

        try
        {
            JSONArray  weeklyflash = json.getJSONArray("GetReportResult");

            for(int i=0;i<weeklyflash.length();i++)
            {                       
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = weeklyflash.getJSONObject(i);

                //map.put("type",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("type", e.getString("type"));
                map.put("total", e.getString("total"));

                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }
        catch(JSONException e)        
        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.wfid, 
                        new String[] { "type", "total" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Closing SecondScreen Activity
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: may be json coming on the different url may differ to each other...

Comment: @DheereshSingh I've check all URL and it shows JSON format properly, the different only `total`'s value

Comment: all json keys are same ? like GetReportResult ? type ?total? all have same keys ?

Comment: Hi try this static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist.

Comment: @DheereshSingh yeah, all keys are same..

Comment: @BhargavPanchal ok I've try that, but it gets error, static is invalid identifier :(